# Swing - JavaFX integration

Tags: java, swing, javafx-2, java-web-start

I have  a bit of a weird problem. I have a swing application that has some windows with are built with JavaFX (Don't ask why I did this, I had to for due to project delivery time restrictions). The app is 50% Swing and 50% javaFx. Anyway what I found when I started deploying the application to customers is that some of the JavaFX JFXPanels that I am using don't display properly

To be more precise JFXPanels that I have in my main window, which are crested as the application starts, are showing fine. Other JFXPanels that I include in other windows that popup while using the application don't display correctly. The JFrame opens up but its empty of JavaFX components. The weird thing is the when I enable Java console (Java-settings -> Advanced -> Show console) everything is working fine.

The same problem I have in all operating systems I deployed the application. 32 and 64 bit.
also I am using JRE 7u25 in all machines.

Any clues anybody?

Comment: Could be a threading issue - when using JFXPanels, you need to be extra careful as some of your GUI stuff has to run on the Swing EDT and some has to run on the FX Thread.

Comment: *"Any cloues anybody?"*  Now you have time, fix that '50% mix'.  Make it one or the other, using whichever threading policy is best practice for the API.  And that, I don't see as being a matter for SO.

Comment: Eventually I will. But for the time being I have to deploy it like that. Its the Java console that its very weird and thought I ask and maybe someone new. I will post here if I find anything

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's related to bug [8021381](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=8021381)?

I appears to be fixed in Java 7u40-b38 according to the [release notes](http://download.java.net/jdk7u40/changes/jdk7u40-b38.html?q=download/jdk7u40/changes/jdk7u40-b38.html)

So I suggest to try out the Java 7u40 early access release ([Download](http://jdk7.java.net/download.html)).

Comment: Other bugs related to Java 7u25:
http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8020626
http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8019274
I wouldn't recommend 7u25 for production use...